# RStudio Error: STRING_ELT() can only be applied to a 'character vector', not a 'builtin'

Tags: r, runtime-error

Upon startup in RStudio. Before doing anything I get the following error display on the console window:

```
Error: STRING_ELT() can only be applied to a 'character vector', not a 'raw'
```

I'm working on a Windows 10 OS R version 3.2.2

How can I get rid of the message? How can I identify where the source of where this error is coming from?  I'm thinking it may have something to do with a previous session but I'm having trouble identifying the pattern for why this error occurs.

Comment: Try starting a clean R session from the command prompt with `R.exe --vanilla` and see if you get this error.

Comment: I'm getting a `'R.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file.`

Comment: That means it's not on your `PATH` variable. Try locating `R.exe` in Windows Explorer, etc.. and using the full file path, e.g. `C:\full\path\to\R.exe --vanilla`.

Comment: `C:\full\path\to\R.exe --vanilla` yields:  `system cannot find the path specified.`

Comment: Well if you put that in literally then I'm not surprised; you'll have to use your actual file path, with appropriate quoting if there are spaces in it.

Comment: lol sorry. Long day I found the path. I'm sorry but I meant to say RStudio and so I used `C:\Program Files\RStudio\bin\Rstudio.exe --vanilla` the same message `system cannot find path`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In RStudio I went to Session - Clear Workspace 
Then I went to Session - Terminate R
Then I went to Session - Restart R

Then I closed the program and restarted it.  Some how that fixed the issue.

Comment: It sounds like this error occurred in your last successful session and the workspace image was saved on exit (which I would recommend not doing, in general).

Comment: Yeah. I no not to do that. I lately I was working in RStudio till I could barely stay awake.  I think I did a force quit that may have saved the workspace image.  I know it's bad because it makes it a hidden data file no?

Comment: As far as I know a `.Rdata` file will be created and continue to occupy RAM even after exiting R. If you need to save objects, you are better off manually saving them (e.g. with `save` or `saveRDS`) and re-loading them in your next session (`load` / `readRDS`).

Comment: @nrussell: Could that also be the case if a script is scheduled and runs via `rscript`.  I have the same error on a script that runs every weekday and the error occurs about once a month. Even if i rerun on same input i cant reproduce it, but it keeps ocurring. Hard to debug,... I  would be thankful for any hints!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error.  In my case, the default Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\R-core\R64\Current Version regkey was pointing to some ancient 2015 version of a Microsoft Revolution Analytics version of R.  Not sure how that happened, but I updated it to point to the latest version of R in C:\Program Files\R\R-4.1.2 and all was well.

YMMV