# Connecting using RAdwords library and using doAuth gives error

Tags: r, google-api, passport-google-oauth

I have been trying to connect to Adwords Account using `RAdwords`, but I get the following error on `doAuth()`:

> Error in
>   rjson::fromJSON(RCurl::postForm("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
>   :    STRING_ELT() can only be applied to a 'character vector', not a
>   'raw'

I have the correct credentials and Developer's token, but I am still unable to resolve the problem. I am using windows 7. The traceback is as follows:

```
> traceback()
    4: .Call("fromJSON", json_str, unexpected.escape, simplify, PACKAGE = "rjson")
    3: rjson::fromJSON(RCurl::postForm("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token", 
       .opts = opts, code = credlist$c.token, client_id = credlist$c.id, 
       client_secret = credlist$c.secret, redirect_uri = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob", 
       grant_type = "authorization_code", style = "POST"))
    2: loadToken(credentials)
    1: doAuth()
```

Looked and tried all options from other similar questions, e.g.: using [suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34184851/rstudio-error-string-elt-can-only-be-applied-to-a-character-vector-not-a)), I have also installed this version of `RAdwords`.

```
install_github('jburkhardt/RAdwords', ref = "refresh_token_raw_data")
```

Comment: I released a possible bug fix of your issue on a new separate GitHub branch of the RAdwords repository. @NKaz could you please reinstall RAdwords from this branch and test again with: ```install_github('jburkhardt/RAdwords', ref = "bugfix_char_to_raw")```

Comment: This new branch has resolved the issue I was facing. I can now successfully connect to Adwords account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the **RAdwords** package from the following GitHub branch containing a bug fix for your issue:

```
require(devtools)
install_github('jburkhardt/RAdwords', ref = "bugfix_char_to_raw")
```