# Error Message when trying to install ggplot2 package in R studio: STRING_ELT() can only be applied to a 'character vector', not a 'NULL'

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to install the ggplot2 package in R. When I enter `install.packages('ggplot2')` in the Console I get the following message **:**

> Error in install.packages : STRING_ELT() can only be applied to a
> 'character vector', not a 'NULL'

I'm stuck, any help anyone can provide would be much appreciated.

OS is **:** Microsoft Windows 10 Education (Version 10.0.19043)
R version is **:** R-3.2.2 ([64-bit]
ggplot2 version is **:** ggplot2_3.3.5

Comment: Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34184851/rstudio-error-string-elt-can-only-be-applied-to-a-character-vector-not-a

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  I second the suggestion for a likely duplicate. Could you care to share your versions of, respectively, your OS, your R version, and the ggplot2 version?  All this works swimmingly on _current_ versions.  If you works with stuff that's years old you may be on your own: most developers follow CRAN and ensure that everything works for _current_ packages.

Comment: I found this earlier post prior to making this post; unfortunately, none of the suggestions in the earlier post worked. The old post is slightly different and refers to the error message: 'character vector', not a 'builtin', my error message is: 'character vector', not a 'NULL'. This is the first time that I have installed RStudio on this machine and I can't get the ggplot2 package to install, very frustrating.

Comment: My OS is Microsoft Windows 10 Education (Version 10.0.19043) my R version is: R-3.2.2 ([64-bit] C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.2), and the ggplot2 version is ggplot2_3.3.5. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If possible, [update R to latest version](https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/) and try again.

Comment: [`R-3.2.2`](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/old/) is almost 7 years old. You will  need to update the R version to use most current package versions (and definitely [`ggplot2`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggplot2/index.html) which needs >= v 3.3)

Comment: That was the issue, I installed version 4.1.2 and ggplot2 installed straight away. Thank you, thank you!!!